# Determine whether $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f'(x) g'(x) \,dx$ is an inner product on $C^1[-1, 1]$

Tags: continuity, inner-products

> Let $S = C^1[-1,1]$ functions, and  define
>   $$\langle f , g \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f'(x)g'(x) \,dx .$$
>   Decide whether $\langle \,\cdot\, , \,\cdot\,\rangle$ is an inner product on $S$.

To decide whether this is an inner product I'm going through the [axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html), and I can't show this one:

> $\langle f,f \rangle  \geq 0$, and equality holds if and only if $f=0$ .

I know that this inner product fails in this axiom for that particular space of functions, but I don't know how to tackle this. Any ideas?

Comment: Take $f=1$ (constant function)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** We will have $\langle f , g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f' g' dx = 0$ if, for example $f' = 0$, that is, if $f$ is constant.